# R Shiny: change the value of the multiple parameter with updateSelectInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a Shiny app in which the inputs that can be selected depend on the database using the `updateSelectInput` function. I want to display the dataframe according different types and to do so, I need to change the value of the `multiple` parameter in `selectInput`.

To be clearer, this is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(WDI)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(foo_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
data <- cbind(head(mtcars), foo)

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",

                 tabPanel(title = "Base 1",
                          fluidRow(
                            dropdownButton(

                              selectInput(
                                inputId = "choice",
                                label = "Type of data",
                                choices = c("Type X",
                                            "Type Y"),
                                selected = "Type X",
                                multiple = FALSE),
                              selectInput(inputId =  "test", 
                                             label = "Test", 
                                             choices = "",
                                          multiple = TRUE),
                              circle = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                              icon = icon("gear"), 
                              width = "300px",
                              tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Outils")
                            ),
                            column(width = 12,
                                   dataTableOutput("data"))
                          ))

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(input$choice == "Type X"){
      updateSelectInput(session,
                           inputId = "test",
                           choices = unique(data$foo_name),
                           selected = NULL)
    }
    else if(input$choice == "Type Y"){
      updateSelectInput(session,
                           inputId = "test",
                           choices = unique(data$foo_name),
                           selected = NULL,
                           multiple = FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$choice == "Type X"){
    data2 <- data %>%
      filter(foo_name %in% input$test)
    }
    else if(input$choice == "Type Y"){
      data3 <- data %>%
        filter(foo_name %in% input$test)
    }
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, when you launch the app and when the type of data is `Type X`, everything works fine: the dataframe is reactively displayed according to the inputs. This works because in the `selectInput` function, the value of the `multiple` parameter is `TRUE`.

However, if I want to display data following `Type Y`, the app stops working. This is because I set the `multiple` parameter as `FALSE`.

Apparently, the `updateSelectInput` function does not accept that we change the value of the `multiple` parameter. Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: If you use `updateSelectizeInput` instead of `updateSelectInput`, you can use `options` and set `maxItems` to 1 or 9999 (see: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1192)

Comment: indeed that works great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ben](/questions/tagged/ben) pointed out, replacing `selectInput` and `updateSelectInput` by `selectizeInput` and `updateSelectizeInput` works. That means that I must remove `multiple = FALSE` and add `options = list(maxItems = 1)` instead, as explained [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1192).

Here's the fixed code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(WDI)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(foo_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
data <- cbind(head(mtcars), foo)

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",

                 tabPanel(title = "Base 1",
                          fluidRow(
                            dropdownButton(

                              selectInput(
                                inputId = "choice",
                                label = "Type of data",
                                choices = c("Type X",
                                            "Type Y"),
                                selected = "Type X",
                                multiple = FALSE),
                              selectizeInput(inputId =  "test", 
                                             label = "Test", 
                                             choices = "",
                                          multiple = TRUE),
                              circle = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                              icon = icon("gear"), 
                              width = "300px",
                              tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Outils")
                            ),
                            column(width = 12,
                                   dataTableOutput("data"))
                          ))

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(input$choice == "Type X"){
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "test",
                           choices = unique(data$foo_name),
                           selected = NULL)
    }
    else if(input$choice == "Type Y"){
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "test",
                           choices = unique(data$foo_name),
                           selected = NULL,
                           options = list(maxItems = 1))
    }
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$choice == "Type X"){
    data2 <- data %>%
      filter(foo_name %in% input$test)
    }
    else if(input$choice == "Type Y"){
      data3 <- data %>%
        filter(foo_name %in% input$test)
    }
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```